# NSImage release() in AppleScriptObjC

Tags: memory-management, release, nsimage, applescript-objc

I'm creating a Table View with small images displayed in each row. The `data source` holds an image for each row of an table. I create images thru `set img to NSImage()'s alloc()'s initWithContentsOfFile_(thePath)`. Next I display the image of selected row in bigger, browser view thru `set imageView's image to img`. Problem is that I'm running out of memory because I use the same representation for both views. (Images are around 500x400).
I'm trying to figure out how to make a smaller version from bigger one and then release a bigger image.

I started from releasing an image..
I have tried `img's release()` but it not worked. I couldn't find any info on that topic besides [Garbage Collection, ARC, and managing memory](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/memory.html). I have turned-on `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` in `XCode` but probably it doesn't applies to Applescript part of a deal. Is there an way to achieve it in pure ApplescriptObjC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (adjusting for your variable names and UI control properties):

```
set curImage to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfFile:thePath

-- create a smaller image

set newImage to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initWithSize:{48, 48}

newImage's lockFocus()

curImage's drawInRect:{{0,0}, {48, 48}} fromRect:{{0,0},{0,0}} operation:2 fraction:1.0

newImage's unlockFocus()

imgArtwork's setImage:newImage 

set curImage to missing value -- release large image
```

Comment: @otakon, the code for image resizing above is adapted from code I use to create images for drag-and-drop feedback. `imgArtwork` is the property for the Image Well control in the UI.

Comment: Thank you for this code, it worked! Now, I need to make test if `set img to missing value` do release the memory in the long run. Thanks Ron! I doesn't use `current application's NSImage's ..` is this approach is some way different memory wise than `property NSImage : class "NSImage"` ?

Comment: @otakon Thanks, since the code worked, please accept the answer above. There a several ways to do the syntax in ASObjC, and they (usually) give the same results, so choose the style you like.

Comment: Thank you Ron, +1! Still I have some issues with memory, the `set img to missing value` doesn't release memory taken by the image. When I import images I do the routine that you posted for each image. The jump in the consumed memory is the same amount as the total weight of imported image files. After conversion to smaller version it suppose to release the memory difference between those two versions, right?

Comment: The variables used in the function/method `on ....()` is released automatically when it comes to the end of it, right? Or is there any method in ASObjC I can call to release all memory taken by this function/method?

Comment: Memory used by Objective-C code with ARC is released if and only if the reference count is zero. If you haven't retained a reference to it in your table rows or elsewhere, it should be released automatically. However, since you are also using AppleScript, it is ***possible*** that memory is not being handled as well as it would be in pure ObjC. I don't know that for a fact, but I have seen, and others have reported, odd memory problems in AppleScript.